# Converting mysql query into hibernate query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a MySQL query, and I want to convert this query in to Hibernate Query. This is what I've tried so far.

```
userInQuery = "SELECT * FROM log where userName in(";
userCountQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM log where userName in(";

for (int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    userInQuery += "'" + users[i] + "',";
    userCountQuery += "'" + users[i] + "',";
}

userInQuery = userInQuery.substring(0, userInQuery.lastIndexOf(","))+ ") and
    systemdate  >= STR_TO_DATE('" + fromDt+ "' ,'%Y-%m-%d') and systemdate  <=
    STR_TO_DATE('"+ toDate + "','%Y-%m-%d')";

userCountQuery = userCountQuery.substring(0, userCountQuery.lastIndexOf(","))+ ")
    and systemdate  >= STR_TO_DATE('"+ fromDt+ "' ,'%Y-%m-%d') and systemdate  <=
    STR_TO_DATE('"+ toDate + "','%Y-%m-%d')";

//System.out.println("Final userInQuery : " + userInQuery);

psmt = conn.prepareStatement(userInQuery);

rscount = stmt.executeQuery(userCountQuery);
```

Comment: Give your MySQL query to get clear idea about what u r asking.

Comment: @user000324 I want to ask how in query  and STR_TO_DATE in hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Hibernate Query :**

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY");
String fromDate = "11-07-2014";
Date fromDt = formatter.parse(fromDate);
String toDate = "11-07-2014";
Date toDt = formatter.parse(toDate);

String userInQuery = "from log where userName in (:userList) and systemdate between :fromDate and :toDate";
Query q = s.createQuery(userInQuery);
q.setParameterList("usersList", users);
q.setParameter("fromDate", fromDt);
q.setParameter("toDate", toDt);
q.list();
```

**Note :** Here :userList, :fromDate & :toDate are query parameters.

**Using Hibernate Criteria :**

```
List<?> users = //get data from either a query or criteria
criteria.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.in("userList", users),Restrictions.between("dateField", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY").parse(fromDate), new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY").parse(toDate)));

OR

criteria.add(Restrictions.in("userList", users));
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("systemDate", fromDt));
criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("systemDate", toDt));
```

Comment: thanks for reply.but I am getting this exception "13:38:57,282 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'Y'
13:38:57,285 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:752)
13:38:57,286 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:559)"

Comment: If u r using **jdk 1.6** then use (lowercase) **y** [SimpleDateFormat - JDK1.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). With **JDK 1.7** u can use the above pattern [SimpleDateFormat - JDK1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: from Log where userName in (:userList) and systemdate between :fromDate and :toDate.
this query returning null?

Comment: Have u set parameters properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of user id's as in your case, and pass that list to below query.

Something like below

```
Select x FROM X x WHERE x.y in :yList
```